# WPF Internationalization using .resx files and updating locale at runtime

Tags: wpf, internationalization, runtime, locale, resx

Can someone show the best solution to internationalize a WPF application for 2 different languges using .resx files for each locale.
I would also like the ability of switching locales at the fly and changing the content of xaml text components at runtime

Answer (score 1):

here is a link which explains step by step on what you need.
reference:
http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/07/26/localizing-a-wpf-program-using-c/

XAML:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.LabelAddress}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,103,0,0" Name="labelAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="119,26,0,0" Name="textBoxFName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" />
```

Code behind:

```
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Configuration;

    Properties.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"]);

//To change the locale in runtime you need to set

    public static void SetLanguage(string locale)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale)) locale = "en-US";
        Properties.Resources.Culture= new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(locale);
    }
```

AppConfig.cs:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Culture" value="zh-CN" />
  </appSettings>
```